# Struts2Url Hiding

Tags: jsp, url, struts2

I want to hide strut2 url....i am accesing ip:port/contextRoot/HideUrl.jsp. In this Jsp there is button, on clicking on this
step1 function of action class is calling and url changes to ip:port/contextRoot/step1Struts2....Can i remain to on original url ip:port/contextRoot/HideUrl.jsp......I dont want to show 'step1Struts2' in url.....can i achieve this and how?

HideUrl.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function callStep1()
       {
           document.struts2Form.action="step1Struts2";
           document.struts2Form.submit();
       }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
      <s:form name="struts2Form">
        <input type="button" value="CallStep1" onclick="callStep1()"></input>

    </s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="struts2" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="*Struts2" class="example.HideUrl" method="{1}">
        <result name="input">HideUrl.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>


<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/*.servlet"/>

   </struts>
```

HideUrl.java

```
package example;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
 import java.util.Map;


 public class HideUrl extends ActionSupport {

 public String step1() throws Exception
{
    Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    System.out.print("[HideUrl] step1 ");
    session.put("step1", "step1");
    return "input";
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Ajax request and update the DOM with the rendered action result.

In general you do *not* want to access a JSP page directly in an MVC app, though.

Another option would be to make a request to an action that simply forwards to the "real" action, essentially making an MVC system within an MVC system.

I don't understand why you'd want to hide the URL.

Comment: Actually i have written my complete code using struts2 and Jsp technology, so in this phase i will not able to use ajax........ I am not able to understand "Another option would be to make a request to an action that simply forwards to the "real" action, essentially making an MVC system within an MVC system.".. Can u please explain more or by any code or example? Is there any option available in struts2?

Comment: @user752590 What do S2 and JSP have to to with Ajax? They're hardly mutually-exclusive. I mean if you want to hide a URL you need to have an action that forwards to the contents instead of redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me you are asking for URL rewriting to hide ugly URLs.

This can be accomplished several ways

1. Through Apache configs
   [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
2. Tomcat URL rewriting, although I've not had much tried this one
   [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Or through a rest type URL configuration:

1. Through STRUTS2 Rest Support (not really rewriting)
   [REST Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html)

I generally use the REST plugin, you just have to be cognizant of the action method names you use. If you don't want it to be step1Struts2 don't name the method step1Struts2, call it process() or something otherwise less...ugly.